# Is there a list of keys and values for VBoxManage setextradata subcommand?

Tags: virtualbox

The `setextradata` subcommand of `VBoxManage` tool of `VirtualBox` 4.3.12 (and others) provides a lot of useful tweaks and even esential features, like activation of symbolic links with `VBoxManage setextradata <VM name> VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/<share name> 1`, but seems to be undocumented systematically. Is there a list (of all keys (and values if there're restrictions) for the command (possibly including supported versions)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I've found that at the moment it's largely undocumented, and there's no real substitute for fishing around in the VirtualBox source code, in parts that are likely to use such settings such as under [src/VBox/Devices](https://www.virtualbox.org/svn/vbox/trunk/src/VBox/Devices), for all the `pfnCFGMQuery`*`Def` calls and figuring out what they do from the code.

Answer (score 2):

I searched for one for years and never found any complete list. There are a lot of "keys" on the "Chapter 9. Advanced Topics" https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html

But I suspect this is just a feature for set "extra" information for advanced tuning features and develop extra features faster than implementing new commands or options.

If I'm correct then we never will found a complete list. An example about that is this test where I can put as "extra data" anything I want, without and error and this invented "extra data" can be retreived also as if was part of VirtualBox (note that `HOST$` is the prompt at host machine):

```
HOST$ VBoxManage setextradata GUEST_VM_NAME VBoxInternal2/testing/a_test 100
HOST$ VBoxManage getextradata GUEST_VM_NAME enumerate
...
Key: VBoxInternal2/testing/a_test, Value: 100
...
HOST$ VBoxManage getextradata GUEST_VM_NAME VBoxInternal2/testing/a_test
Value: 100
HOST$
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for WM-NAME, without some "global" params.

https://gist.github.com/hazg/9f4ccaf7f160f817f7f288b5686be077

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1123543)